# Fijar el body max-height a 100% según cierto contenido

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo una página en donde necesito que el alto máximo del contenido no supere el 100% de la pantalla.

El contenido de la página posee ciertos divs con un height fijo pero hay otro div que sí puede variar su height dependiendo de su contenido, éste solo tiene un min-height establecido. Necesito que su alto no haga que el contenido total de la página supere el 100% del alto de la pantalla, pero no encuentro cómo limitarlo para que respete eso.

**Edit:**
Aclaro: La sumatoria del alto dinámico con los otros dos altos estáticos no debe superar el alto total de la pantalla.

Esto tengo hasta ahora, intenté limitar el alto del body pero no da resultado, el div del que hablo es el que tiene la clase "minHeight":

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
    body{
        max-height: 100% !important;
    }
    .h50{
        height: 50px;
        background-color: rgb(230,230,230);
    }
    .minHeight{
        min-height: 50px;
        background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Some element outside the main container</div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row h50"></div>
        <div class="row minHeight">
            <div class="col-12">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row h50"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Excorpion planeo limitar el alto de ese contenido dinámico, haciéndolo scrollable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisa si esto te sirve...

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.h50{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(230,230,230);
}
    
.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.minHeight {
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 100px); /* 100px es el alto sumado de los dos .h50 */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body>
    <div>Some element outside the main container</div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row h50"></div>
        <div class="row minHeight">
            <div class="col-12">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row h50"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: acabo de aplicar lo que sugieres pero no funciona. Por cierto, lo de tu ejemplo es justamente lo que intento que no pase.

Comment: Pero leiste lo que coloque el final?

Comment: sí, he dicho que acabo de aplicarlo pero no da el resultado que mencionas. Puse todo dentro de un contenedor padre y le fijé height: 100vh. Si estás seguro de que funciona podrías ejemplificarlo?

Comment: Es que hay cosas que no están claras, quieres que este no supere el 100% pero... que quieres que pase con el contenido que supere este alto? que no aparezca, que haga scroll?, que hace h50?

Comment: exacto, que haga scroll. la clase h50 simplemente está fijando un alto fijo a las otras dos divs, eso está claro en el código.

Comment: ok déjame ver como te ayudamos

Comment: He editado el código, revisa si te sirve

Comment: eso es perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

...
Por supuesto, si el contenido es dinámico, en algún momento el 100% de la altura, se superará. 
El tema está en que hacer con el contenido extra.
Lo que yo propongo es controlarlo con `overflow`. 
Y tenemos 2 opciones, esconderlo o hacerlo scroll.

```css
body{
        max-height: 100% !important;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .h50{
        max-height: 80%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: rgb(230,230,230);
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .minHeight{
        min-height: 50px;
        background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
        max-height: 80vh;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>Some element outside the main container</div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row h50"></div>
        <div class="row minHeight">
            <div class="col-12">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row h50"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Lo malo aquí es que estás fijando un max-height para el div de contenido dinámico.

Comment: Claro, por el scroll que mencionaste que quieres agregarle. El max-height afecta la visualizacion, no el contenido. Si agregas un scroll, agregar un height es necesario.

Comment: Si, pero para este caso el height con calc() va mas a lugar que fijar un max-height arbitrariamente. Gracias en todo caso.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estás usando Bootstrap puedes limitar la altura máxima del `body` al tamaño vertical de la pantalla con esto:

```
<body class="min-vh-100">
```

---

También puedes asignar una altura máxima a los componentes internos del `body` usando la clase `mh-100`. En este caso, el número al final representa un porcentaje del tamaño total del `body`.

Este es un ejemplo de un `body` que ocupa como máximo el 100% de la pantalla y dos componentes a su interno que ocupan un 50% (cada uno) de ese total:

```
<body class="min-vh-100">
    <div class="mh-50">
        <!--Contenido que ocupa el 50% de la pantalla-->
    </div>
    <div class="mh-50">
        <!--Contenido que ocupa el 50% restante de la pantalla-->
    </div>
</body>
```

---

Considera también si es el caso de añadir una barra para facilitar el desplazamiento a través del contenido. Con Bootstrap se puede hacer de esta manera:

```
<div class="overflow-auto">...</div>
```